# Create Categories and Products in wordpress without plugins

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and i want to create a online shopping store. So i just want to know how to create a categories and products without using any plugin. Please also tell me which one is better approach with plugins or without plugins. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find a category Widget. Use that

Comment: thanks for reply. I used wp_list_categories( $args ); and my all custom taxonomy are displaying properly. But now i want to display all products related to that categories. So when i click on any category my url looks like http://localhost/WordCart/product_categories/kids-clothing/. For this i created a archive.php but still the index page is running. Can you suggest which page i shuould create to display my products?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a plug in for custom categories and custom types depends in the complexity and the amount of the categories and types of your site you want to build.
Either ways I recommend you to use Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Types which are both Free and efficient.

Found here:
[http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/][1]

[http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/][1]